# Одни и те же значения в словарях внутри списка PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Имеются следующие данные

```
board = [
  ["E","A","R","A"],
  ["N","L","E","C"],
  ["I","A","I","S"],
  ["B","Y","O","R"]
]
word = "EARS"
```

Нужно пробежаться по слову и зафиксировать в словарь линии и столбцы нахождения буквы в массиве

Код:

```
 for symbol in word:

    POSITIONS = [item.index(symbol) for item in board if symbol in item]
    LINES = [board.index(item) for item in board if symbol in item]

    dict["LINES"] = LINES
    dict["POSITIONS"] = POSITIONS

    list.append(dict)
```

Но при запуске получается печальный результат - словарь почему-то обновляется во всём списке, такого не должно быть, не понимаю в чем проблема
[image: Результат]

Comment: Про dict код не приведен. Он у вас всего один?

Comment: @MBo Да, вначале создан только один dict = {}

Comment: dict["LINES"] = dict["LINES"] + LINES

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, я нашёл решение)

Answer (score 0):

```
 for symbol in word:

POSITIONS = [item.index(symbol) for item in board if symbol in item]
LINES = [board.index(item) for item in board if symbol in item]
dict = {}
dict["LINES"] = LINES
dict["POSITIONS"] = POSITIONS

list.append(dict)
```